# How to identify hardcoded database name - SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find a way to determine what object in a database has the original database name hardcoded into it.  I've restored a copy of a database under a different name and run homegrown scripts to make all the naming adjustments.  Let's say the original DB was named ABC_Db and the restored copy has been renamed to XYZ_Db.  When I attempt to perform an UPDATE on CoreTable, I get

Invalid object name 'ABC_Db.dbo.CoreTable'

I've queried against the syscomments and done various manual checks against relations and indexes, etc. with no luck.  What's next?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search through a Microsoft SQL Server database schema, the best tool is RedGate's SQL Search - and it's free.  It's awesome.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: Found it!  They were in an auxiliary database that would've taken me days to get to searching the way I was.  I bhink I like this SQL Search.

Answer (score 3):

To find it

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM
   sys.sql_modules
WHERE
   definition LIKE '%ABC_Db%'
```

syscomments is unreliable for long code.

sys.sql_modules covers all code and is safe for all objects

Answer (score 2):

`sys.syscomments` text is nvarchar(4000) so you can have issues with truncation when a definition splits across multiple rows. Try this instead.

```
select quotename(s.name)+'.'+quotename(o.name) as object_name, o.type_desc
    from sys.sql_modules m
        inner join sys.objects o 
            on m.object_id = o.object_id
        inner join sys.schemas s 
            on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where m.definition like '%ABC_Db%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to generate db scripts and use a text editor search in files tool to find if such thing is there in any stored proc or other code.

Answer (score 0):

Could there be a trigger that has the full object name hard-coded?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Prompt 5 has a feature called "Find Invalid Objects", which will identify stored procedures that reference objects that don't exist. It could be worth a try.